# TelephonyManager getstate() returns zero in android

Tags: java, android

In my application, I want to put a log for the state when someone picks up the call. The getState() on the switch statement must return the correct state of the call, but it always returns zero. Here is my onRecieve() method:

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)){
        incomingFlag = false;
        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.i(TAG, "call OUT:"+phoneNumber);
        TelephonyManager tm =
                (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Log.e("log state", String.valueOf(tm.getCallState()));
        switch (tm.getCallState()) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                incomingFlag = true;
                incoming_number = intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number");
                Log.i(TAG, "RINGING :"+ incoming_number);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if(incomingFlag){
                    Log.i(TAG, "incoming ACCEPT :"+ incoming_number);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if(incomingFlag){
                    Log.i(TAG, "incoming IDLE");
                }
                break;
                default:
                    Log.e("ds","Error");
        }
    }
```

manifest file :

```
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".BroadCast" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

The onCreate() method mentioned above is in a seperate class I created called BroadCast, and I call it by creating a new instance of it.

Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: what about permissions?

Comment: question updated bro

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a BroadcastReceiver to handle the incoming call.
In your onResume, set up the receiver

```
IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
filter2.setPriority(99999);
this.registerReceiver(incomingCallReceiver, filter2);
```

and handle it such as

```
BroadcastReceiver incomingCallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle == null) return;
        // Incoming call

        // Get the state
        String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        // Process the states
        if ((state != null) &&  (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) {
            // Ringing State
        }
        if ((state != null) &&  (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))) {
            // Idle State
        }
        if ((state != null) &&  (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))) {
            // Offhook State
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: how can I get the state? I am new to BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: The state information is obtained through the bundled EXTRA data. I have added checks for your original states.